# Javascript - Adding 30 Days to Input Date

Tags: javascript, date, input

I can't seem to find anything recent, and it's possible I might be behind the times and am just searching the wrong terms and such so I am hoping someone here can be helpful or might have some suggestions.

I have two date fields, one an invoice date and one a due date. What I'd like to happen is that I choose or change a date in the invoice date and the due date is automatically updated to reflect a date 30 days after the invoice date.

```
<input id="dateInvoice" type="date"/>
<input id="dueDate" type="date"/>
```

Comment: You want to add 30 days or 1 month? Both are not identical.

Comment: getDate / setDate is all you'll need - javascript handles overflows for you

Comment: @gurvinder372 - you are correct, I have altered my question to reflect a uniform question

Comment: *I have two date fields, one an invoice date and one a due date* Are these input date type tags? Can you share relevant markup?

Comment: `dueDate = new Date(invoideDate); dueDate.setDate(dueDate.getDate() + 30)`

Comment: @gurvinder372 - I have updated the question with the markup. Currently, they are date fields, but that can be changed if necessary. What I'd like is to use some form of uniformity (either through the browser date picker or jquery datepicker) rather than a text field just to make sure there isn't any confusion by an end user.

Comment: @Matthew So, your question is how to retrieve a date object from user-input in the input type-date field?

Comment: @gurvinder372 - yes, and then the dueDate field is updated using the invoiceDate value (plus 30 days) that was put in by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this approach

- **parse the input date** value to date using `split` and *date constructor*
- Add days using `setDate`
- *Set the new date value* to output date.

**Demo**

```js
document.querySelector("#addDays").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var invoiceDate = document.querySelector("#invoiceDate").value;
  var days = Number(document.querySelector("#days").value);
  var dueDateElement = document.querySelector("#dueDate");

  if (!isNaN(days) && invoiceDate.length) {
    invoiceDate = invoiceDate.split("-");
    invoiceDate = new Date(invoiceDate[0], invoiceDate[1] - 1, invoiceDate[2]);
    invoiceDate.setDate(invoiceDate.getDate() + days);
    dueDateElement.valueAsDate = null;
    dueDateElement.valueAsDate = invoiceDate;
    //console.log(invoiceDate, dueDateElement.value);
  }
});
```

```html
Invoice Date <input type="date" id="invoiceDate"> <br><br> Add Days <input type="text" id="days"> <br><br>

<button id="addDays">Add Days</button> <br><br> Due Date <input type="date" id="dueDate">
```

Comment: I like this one, so I know that means my request is possible in some form. Using the above code as a template, does there look to be a way to perform the same action automatically after the invoice date is changed?

Comment: You can invoke the same code at the `change` event of your *invoice date* as well.

Comment: Hi - I got yours to work in the way I needed using the change event, but it looks like mine (as well as the demo you provided run into a problem when the new year is introduced. For example, try 12/22/2017 as the invoice date, and the days as 30 and you'll see that the due date will stay at mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Oddly enough, the same problem occurs with any date before 11/10/2017 as well.

Comment: Ohh, let me check then.

Comment: @Matthew It is working now. Once you have set a date once to date control programmatically, you need to clear the same before setting a new one. It is fixed, please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the date in Javascript like this

```
var date = new Date(2017,11,27,11,14,00,00)
```

you can add 30 days to this date to get the date (after 30 days)

```
after30days = date.setDate(cur.getDate() + 30);
```

Comment: How would I go about using this after inputting / updating the invoice date? I can't seem to get a date field to work with changing the date field.

Comment: @Matthew which plugin you used for Date ?, if it's simple input date, try document.getElementById("date").value

Comment: So would this be correct for a final output? It seems it doesn't want to do anything with the due date: `<script>
    function invoicedue(e){
        alert(e.target.value);
        var invoiceDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dateInvoice").value);
        var dueDate1 = invoiceDate.setDate(cur.getDate() + 30);
        $('#dueDate').val(dueDate1);
        
}   
</script>`

Comment: the value must be in "yyyy-MM-dd" format when we set the value to input date, use this function to get the last step done https://stackoverflow.com/a/3067896/713789

Answer (score 0):

you can split the javascript date into month day and year and add simple month to it
as

```
var invoiceDate = new Date("01/31/2017");
var dueDate= invoiceDate.addMonths(1);
```

Comment: or u can add same gor days like :                                                             var dueDate= invoiceDate.addDays(30);

Comment: How would I go about using this after inputting / updating the invoice date? I can't seem to get a date field to work with changing the date field.

Comment: i didnt get your your question will you please explain me what exactl wou want to say

Comment: So an example would be, as someone adds or changes the invoice date field, the due date field will automatically be updated with the add 30 days (or one month, I don't really care so long as I get some form of a solution)

Comment: @Matthew you can use onchange event if you it's input date, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762843/713789

Comment: So would this be correct for a final output? It seems it doesn't want to do anything with the due date: `<script>
    function invoicedue(e){
        alert(e.target.value);
        var invoiceDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dateInvoice").value);
        var dueDate1 = invoiceDate.setDate(cur.getDate() + 30);
        $('#dueDate').val(dueDate1);
        
}   
</script>`