# Changes Occur Before onchange() Event

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I am trying to add an onchange event to a date field on my html page:

```
<input class="userinfo" id="strBoB"type="date" onchange="checkDoB();"/>
```

The JavaScript I have written is:

```
function checkDoB(){

    //Setup function specific variables:
    var strDoB = document.getElementById("strBoB").value;
    alert(strDoB);
    var intCount = 0;
    var j=0;

}
```

It seams to trigger as soon as I start editing the year section of the date field.

Comment: Because you changed it.

Comment: Sounds like you want the onblur event instead

Comment: check [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change), scroll down, then you will find the important information at **Description**.

Comment: Did you try using it as `onchange="checkDoB"` instead of `onchange="checkDoB();"`?

Comment: Maybe this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762549/html5-input-type-date-onchange-event

Comment: @IFebles - That won't work for an inline html attribute `onchange`. (Actually it wouldn't work in a script block either, not with quotes around the function name.)

Comment: Thanks for the info @nnnnnn! The actual behavior for the `onchange` event is that it will trigger once the input value changes, so it's what it should do. I'm with @SterlingArcher about the `onblur` event; maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: *onchange* is supposed to fire when the element loses focus and it's value has changed, but some browsers don't wait for loss of focus, e.g. select elements, it's a bit mixed. It has nothing to do with host settings, just implementation choices over which you have no control (unless you wrote the browser you're using).

Comment: @SterlingArcher If you add an answer, I will vote up and mark as right.

Comment: I had a similar issue and wrote an answer to the following post, in which I explained the different occurences of change/blur events. Maybe useful for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57467732/11917963

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onblur event is what worked for this issue.

Change from this:

```
<input class="userinfo" id="strBoB"type="date" onchange="checkDoB();"/>
```

To this:

```
<input class="userinfo" id="strBoB"type="date" onblur="checkDoB();"/>
```