# What is the difference between the onChange and onInput events in a date input tag?

Tags: javascript, html

In vanilla JavaScript, if you have an html tab

```
<input type="date" />
```

What, if any, is the difference between the onChange event and onInput event.

Normally, onChange doesn't trigger until the user actually clicks out of the tag (or for some other reason the onBlur event is triggered) but as I understand it, with type="date", it is triggered whenever there is any change to the text in the box that results in a valid date. This can result in onChange being triggered just by the user moving between the month, day and year fields in the box.

This seems to be very similar to how onInput works.

Normally, you could attach a function to onBlur but, when using the calendar widget to input the date, the control still has focus after the calendar closes. And there doesn't seem to be any event triggered by the closing of the calendar from which to call blur. So you have to click outside of the box even after using the calendar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 <input type=“date”> - onChange Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762549/html5-input-type-date-onchange-event)

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It's just another way that JavaScript is a mess.

Comment: True, there are a lot of custom date libraries out there if you want a better date module than the one given by browsers.